# How to show save dialog box in nreco html to pdf generator in c#

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

```
 var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();

 htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile(baseUrl, null,"exprt.pdf");
```

Here Before Downloading want to open save as dialog box in C#.

Thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, I solved with this process
public Stream GeneratePDF()
{  
    var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter(); 
    var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("http://url", null);  
    byte[] buffer = pdfBytes;
    int sum = 0;
    int count;
    while ((count = buffer.Length - sum) > 0)
    {
        sum += count;
    } 
    return new MemoryStream(buffer); 
}

Best Regards and good luck!!